# Foundation 4 with off canvas menu

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to figure out what foundation 4's main page is doing.

I want to replicate the menu on the their homepage http://foundation.zurb.com/

In their docs it says off-canvas templates are for 3.2 and not tested for 4.0.  In the source on the main page the body class is listed as off-canvas.

```
<body class="off-canvas hide-extras">
```

I don't see any references to off-canvas in the documentation other than the templates.

So are they using an off-canvas, untested template on their own home page? Or is off-canvas type menu something achievable in 4.0 in a new fashion that I can't seem to find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you're fixed on 4.0, but 5.0 does include off-canvas in its documentation
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html

Comment: This is what I did end up using. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try Jpanel menu or slidebars. They can be used with any template.. not limited to bootstrap or foundation

http://jpanelmenu.com/#tips 
 http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars/

Answer (score -2):

Check this out:
http://zurb.com/playground/off-canvas-layouts

Looks like the off-canvas layouts were an added feature to Foundation 3. I'm not sure if the off-canvas layouts we're carried out into Foundation 4.

Comment: Yes, mentioned those.  I'm trying to find out if they are using 3.2 layout on their 4.0 page or if there is any other way to do off canvas with 4.0